# Windows 10 Enterprise, user account missing at log-on screen

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I'm using Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Edition OS and I have 2 accounts on my laptop. One account is for my personal stuff and the other one is for my job which is registered on a domain. Now the 2nd account (for my job) suddenly disappears this morning, now I have my personal account as sign-in option and another account with username `admin`, when I sign into my personal account and navigate to `C:\Users\MyBusinessAccountName` I still have all of my data, but no option whatsoever to log into this account at log-in screen.

What approach should I take to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Press Win + X keys and select Computer Management.

Navigate to System tools\Local users and groups\Groups\Administrators

Add your domain account into the Administrators group.

Restart computer.

When you need to login system by your job account, note format

User: Domain\username

Password: job account’s password

Disable the GPO: Interactive logon: Don’t display last signed-in

Comment: My work account user is already member of `Administrators` group, the problem is when I turn on my laptop I'm not given an option to log in as that user, here are some screenshots: http://prntscr.com/jca59y , http://prntscr.com/jca5yf

Comment: Also, this is my `C:\Users\` folder content: http://prntscr.com/jcamot , the job folder has all of my work-user-account related data in it, but the problem is I have no means of logging into that account.

Comment: Also it may help knowing that since my work account went missing from log-in screen, an admin account appeared, but I can't log into it, there is a password hint though which states `'default'` as the hint.